# mongodb drop collection error unexpected token illegal

Tags: mongodb

i have create a collection

> db.createCollection("user1@mail.com_test")
>
> { "ok" : 1 }

but, if i try to drop the collection i have a error **E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

> db.user1@mail.com_test.drop() **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
>
> db.user1\@mail.com_test.drop() **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
>
> db."user1@mail.com_test".drop() **SyntaxError: Unexpected string**

How can I drop user1@mail.com_test collection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your collection contains `.` inside name. It is possible, but considered a bad practice. To get such collection you can use [`getCollection()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) method:

```
db.getCollection("user1@mail.com_test").drop()
```